# Оптимизация UITableView

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Создал `UITableView` с кастомными ячейками, в которых выводится картинка (640х100) на всю ячейку. Всего 16 ячеек и при скроллинге все это дело немного подлагивает. Что нужно сделать, чтобы не подтормаживало? Т.к. я видел приложения с теми же картинками, но ничего не тормозило.

Comment: Используете ли Вы метод: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`?

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум - реюз ячеек, второе, покажите6 как вы сетите отображаете картинки?

Comment: да, я использую dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

создал кастомный tablecellview в котором всю ячейку занимает картинка. 
и в вью контроллере, в методе cellForRowAtIndexPath я вставляю в cell.cellImage.image = [UIimage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

Comment: Храни все изображения в массиве, не стоит их грузить каждый раз при 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: ух ты, а как иницилиазировать их заранее?

Answer (score 1):

1. Загрузите все изображения в память `UIImage` с помощью  `initWithData`. Существенное время уходит не только на закачку картинки из интернета или считывание с диска, но и на раскодирование картинки. Поэтому это лучше сделать заранее и хранить изображения в памяти.
2. Размер `UIImageView` должен точно совпадать с размером изображения. Если картинки больше или меньше `UIImageView`, то пережмите их заранее. Этим мы сократим расход памяти и процессорное время, необходимое на пересжатие картинок.
3. `imageView.clipsToBounds = NO`.
4. `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter`. В пп. 3 и 4 немножко выиграем время на отрисовке картинок.

А вообще код `cellForRowAtIndexPath` в студию.